# Admob Milkmangames tool not working

Tags: android, flash, admob, cs4

We are trying to show ads on our android device using the milkman tool for admon available , now after we failed to display the ads , we contacted the creator of this service he has also failed to help us. Is there any one who has implemented the tool and can provide us with the descriptor file and as3 code to implement this -- below is what we do in cs4:

On the frame where we want the ads to display ----

```
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.AdMob;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.*;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.AdMob;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.AdMobAdType;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.AdMobAlignment;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.events.AdMobEvent;


if(AdMob.isSupported)
{
    AdMob.init("xxxxxxxxxxx");
}

AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.BANNER,AdMobAlignment.LEFT,AdMobAlignment.CENTER);
```

Then we add the swc file to the library ---
Then we make changes to the descriptor file adding the  tag,

Then we add all the permissions --then from command like we do this -

```
 adt -package -target apk-debug -storetype pkcs12 -keystore f:\keys\carp12.p12 -storepass abcd1234 testfile.apk  carmobileversion-app.xml roadf.png road72.png carmobileversion.swf -extdir d:\ane
```

But we keep getting error that the swf version in com.extensions.Admob is 11 while the root swf is 10. We have overlayed sdk 3.5 already.

Can any one can help us with this ?

Comment: Just to let every one know , the issue has been resolved, alex the creator of this tool helped us in this, we just needed to use newly released files, we were using old ones ...great tool ...

Answer (score 0):

Just to let every one know , the issue has been resolved, alex the creator of this tool helped us in this, we just needed to use newly released files, we were using old ones ...great tool ...